# Issue with easy_install-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install

After installing easy_install and trying to use it to then install a python package it fails.

```
[root@server]# easy_install-2.7 pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
```

I seem to get a redirect

```
curl -IL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Retry-After: 0
Location: https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 10:28:40 GMT
Age: 0
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 10:28:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-PYPI-LAST-SERIAL: 835141
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 3933
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 78434
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install the OpenSSL development package and then reinstall Python 2.7, in order to enable SSL (and hence HTTPS) support.

Comment: Thanks!  I found it a little annoying that in this day and age Python2.7's make doesn't put up a GIANT FLASHING warning when you are missing the openssl-devel package/libraries... :-)

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSUSE (tested with 42.2), installing `python-pyOpenSSL` is enough -- no `openssl-devel` or reinstallation necessary.