# Installing pip using easy_install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I don't have root access and i want to install python from scratch. So I downloaded the python source code and compiled it. Next I wanted to install `pip`. But when I ran `python get-pip.py` I got this error:

`ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler`

Not having root access then I couldn't install stuff needed. So I thought maybe I can install `pip` with `easy_install` so I went and installed `setuptools` which has `easy_install`. But when I run `easy_install pip` I get this error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

So now how to install `pip`? I'm really going crazy!

Edit: I can't use `virutalenv`

Comment: Why can't you use virtualenv

Comment: Check this post..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926683/issue-with-easy-install-2-7

Answer (score 20):

> try this to install pip :  "easy_install-2.7 -U --user pip"

```
**another important info**
```

To install pip on Ubuntu, Debian or Linux Mint:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

To install pip on Fedora:

```
$ sudo yum install python-pip
```

To install pip on CentOS, first enable EPEL repository, and then run:

```
$ sudo yum install python-pip
```

To install pip on Archlinux:

```
$ sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

Comment: i have no root access!

Comment: you may add sudo zypper install python-pip for suse

Answer (score 8):

This isn't precisely answering original question but if you're unfortunate enough to be trying to install `pip` with `easy_install` on centos6, I hope this helps.

This used to work but now fails with below error:

```
$ docker run -ti centos:6 bash -c 'yum install -y python-setuptools && easy_install pip'
...
Installed:
  python-setuptools.noarch 0:0.6.10-3.el6                                                                                                                       

Complete!
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

I guess http://pypi.python.org got serious about requiring `https`.
If you make this little hack then `easy_install pip` works.

`sed --in-place 's#http://pypi.python.org#https://pypi.python.org#g' /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py`

Comment: It gets worse, now centos6 users need to stick with pip 9.0.3. The latest (pip 10) breaks centos 6.9 compatibility which seems crazy since centos6 is still supported and there are still tons of users and python is installed by default on centos. E.g. docker run -ti centos:6 bash -c 'yum install -y python-setuptools && easy_install pip==9.0.3 && pip install restnavigator'

Answer (score 5):

For those who have **no root access**, here is how I solved the issue.

1. Download Python (Gzipped source tarball).
2. Unzip and cd to the Python source directory.
3. Configure with the "--with-ensurepip=install" flag, e.g.,

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=[your-specified-dir] --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib64 --with-ensurepip=install
   ```
4. make & make install
5. Now you should have a working but out-dated pip.  To get the latest pip, download the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file and run python get-pip.py

Now you should have the latest pip.  Enjoy.  :)

Answer (score -1):

Virtualenv to the rescue!  It comes with pip, doesn't require root access, and allows you to have different environments each with their own copy of python, pip, and modules.  [The installation docs](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) list several installation methods, you want the last one called "Use locally from source".  Please also have a look at [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is just a set of shell scripts that makes working with virtualenv easier.  Google will produce ample tutorials on both of these.

Comment: Why the negative loves?

Answer (score -1):

pip installation is concern confirm with your python version in my case i m using python3 so i use following command and it works . let's try this

i am using MacOS

$ python3 get-pip.py

Answer (score -1):

Gave me lot of trouble too but this worked for me:

python3 get-pip.py