# Not able to install pip

Tags: python, pip

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

getting below error(new to django and python)

```
Searching for pip

Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Comment: Easiest way to install pip is from your [package manager](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/). The next way is to follow the [installation guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) on the pip website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279207/installing-pip-using-easy-install

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your system's package manager.

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

or

```
yum install python3-pip
```

Also you can download 
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
and do

```
python3 get-pip.py
```