# Error SSL with python (https)

Tags: python, ssl, https, debian, python-telegram-bot

I am under debian 8

I'd tried to instal : python-telegram-bot (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) but when I did "python setup.py install" it make an error :

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_telegram_bot-5.3.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for python-telegram-bot==5.3.1 Searching for certifi 
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
```

So I have tried to re-install python 2.7.13 with open-ssl:

```
apt-get install opensll
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I edited the /Modules/setup.dist :

```
# Socket module helper for socket(2)
_socket socketmodule.c timemodule.c

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable: SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

After that, I ran ./configure and make && make install

I have the error :during install :

```
Makefile:1081: recipe for target 'libinstall' failed make: *** [libinstall] 
Error 1
```

And python-telegram-bot would'n compile ...

Can someone have a idea ?

Thanks you very much.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to reinstall python2.7 after installing OpenSSL, as was suggested in the following stackoverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926770/3826254

Or simply use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install the python package instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error when I was trying to install **python2.7.13** from **[source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz)**.

I tried a lot of things and after spending a lot of time got to know that one of the library `libreadline6-dev` was missing.

So installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
```

and it worked fine for me.

Here are the commands which I used to compile and make install (inside Python-2.7.13 directory:

```
./configure --prefix /usr/bin/python2.7.13
sudo make altinstall
```